# Sendmail is not sending out email in XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, sendmail

I recently installed XAMPP on my Windows 2008 server (64 bit) and trying to configure the mail server to use SendMail but for some reason it's not working.

My setting in the PHP.ini is:

```
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost
SMTP = IMC-EXCH-CLUS.ourhospitalname.com
smtp_port = 25
auth_username = myemailusername
auth_password = mypass
sendmail_from = myemailusername@myhospitalname.com
```

The PHP/MYSQL page seems to not give me any error and successfully executes the script.

How do I check to make sure that my email information is set up correctly in the INI file? If it is, what else do I have to do to successfully use SendMail?

Comment: check the smtp server's logs to see what came in on its end of things. you can also check stuff like `netstat` on the server's console to see if there actually is a connection attempt to the smtp server when you run your script.

Comment: Where is that located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found this in google:**
You can send mail from localhost with sendmail package , sendmail package is inbuild in XAMPP. So if you are using XAMPP then you can easily send mail from localhost.

for example you can configure `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`

and `c:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini` for gmail to send mail.

in `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` find `extension=php_openssl.dll` and remove the semicolon from the beginning of that line to make SSL working for gmail for localhost.

in php.ini file find `[mail function]` and change

`SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = my-gmail-id@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"`

Now Open `C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini`. Replace all the existing code in `sendmail.ini` with following code

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
auth_password=my-gmail-password
force_sender=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
```

Now you have done!! create php file with mail function and send mail from localhost.

*PS: don't forgot to replace my-gmail-id and my-gmail-password in above code.*

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have a new email created in our exchange server which I want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 64 bit is not supported by this function, take a look at this line in PHP.ini:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
```

Comment: Check this out -: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576212/php-ini-how-to-use-sendmail-from-in-windows-64-bit