# php.ini : how to use sendmail_from in Windows 64 bit?

Tags: php, apache, email

I have a multi-site php 5.5 server on Windows 2008 R2 64 bit.

I want to force all php mail() scripts to use "sendmail_from" in php.ini
Problem : php.ini say "; For Win32 only." about sendmail_from

Do you have an idea to force all php scripts using mail() to use a defined sendmail_from ?

Thanks

Comment: you might also need fake sendmail for windows http://wiki.uniformserver.com/index.php/Installing_Fake_Sendmail_for_Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows API is called win32, regardless of if you're on 64-bit Windows or not.  The setting will work on your 64-bit server just fine.